# Symfony2, Doctrine2: non english/letin slug

Tags: utf-8, symfony, doctrine-orm, slug

i have a community, where users can make their own topics, also in international languages like hebrew or arabic

i have the "name" field of the topic, and i want to generate slugs out of it

now i have tested it with arabic, using the stofdoctrineBundle and Doctrine extensions

i set up the slug like this

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
private $slug;
```

and when i try to make a new topic with arabic, say this string "علي قرا", doctrine sluggable generated the following **slug: ly-qr**

so my goal is to have complete URL like this

http://www.mysite.com/علي-قرا

for SEO reasons.

Comment: Maybe you should file an issue here : https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of the slugifier in gedmo's doctrine extensions is to convert all characters to ASCII.

If you don't want this behavior, you will have to create either your own *handler* and/or your own *transliterator* method.

The docs [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md) explain well how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Florian, i tried your way, but it looked way too complicated for my needs, so i went an easier path:

- completely disabled doctrine extensions
- created a new class under Utils\MyFunctions, and put the static method slugify which is based on symfony2 blog tutorial.
- when setting the name, i also set the slug with it

  ```
  public function setName($name)
  {
   $this->name = $name;
   $this->setSlug($this->name);
  }

  public function setSlug($slug)
  {

    //now we generate the slug, from the utilities my function
    $slug = Myfunctions::slugify($slug);
    $this->slug = $slug;
  }
  ```

Problem solved, and arabic now showing fine as a slug.

Comment: hello, how did you solve this please ? I have the same problem